# Android : androidx.media3.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException: Source error

Tags: android, service, exoplayer, android-media3

I am trying to implement an Audio Player using the Latest [Media3 of Jetpack Compoonent](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media#jetpack_media3) in Android using the service [MediaSessionService](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/session/mediasessionservice#using-mediasessionservice).

Here's the error screenshot:

[image]

Here's my code for initializing the exoplayer in my Service class.

```
exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
```

Here's my code for setting a URL in exoplayer to play an Audio

```
val mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri("AUDIO-URL-HERE")

        exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
        exoPlayer.prepare()
        exoPlayer.play()
```

I have already tried StackOverflow's [solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66132127/unable-to-catch-exoplaybackexception-source-error) , [solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73689400/playback-error-e-exoplayer-exoplayer2-exoplaybackexception-source-error-while) , [solution3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50489829/exoplayer-source-error) but nothing helped.

The listener is also added to catch this error and this error code is 2005 (see attached screenshot which has yellow colored log line)

Any help will be really appreciated.

Just for reference, I am using these testing URLs of Audio files which gives me the error:

1. https://file-examples.com/storage/fe235481fb64f1ca49a92b5/2017/11/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3
2. https://www.learningcontainer.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Kalimba.mp3

Comment: Did you get any solution for that, I am also facing same issue.

Comment: If you are testing this on emulator, check your wifi connection in emulator. Check whether you are able to load any data from website or not before playing any audio.